# Mixed authentication and single sign on with Azure Active Directory and ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, asp.net-core-webapi, microsoft-identity-web

I am working on an existing ASP.NET Core 3.1 web API. The existing authentication scheme is JWT. There is a new requirement that we support Single Sign on using Azure Active Directory.

So, I thought that the strategy I want to follow is to authenticate a user with Microsoft and when my signin-oidc URL callback is called, I will use the token from Microsoft to match my application's user. Then I will produce my existing JWT just the way the application already does, to authorize further actions. Therefore, I want to authenticate with Microsoft but then carry on with the older authorization scheme.

And now the problem. As far as I understand, the signin-oidc URL is not something that you define yourself but is rather hidden somewhere inside `Microsoft.Identity.Web`.

Nevertheless, based on the description above, I concluded that I have to define it. So, what is the proper way to implement it? My implementation below works but something tells me I am missing something crucial to security.

```
[HttpPost("signin-oidc")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[RequireHttps]
public IActionResult AuthorizeAzureAD([FromForm] OIDCForm form)
{
    var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var token = jwtHandler.ReadJwtToken(form.id_token);
    var claims = token.Claims.ToArray();

    // Use the nonce claim to make sure that this callback is initiated by me.
    var guidClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "nonce");

    if (guidClaim == null || !_azureGuids.TryRemove(guidClaim.Value, out string guid))
        return Unauthorized();

    return Ok(/* return the old JWT to the application for further communication. */);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> **On Workaround you can use the  OpenID connect for SSO**

Here is some documents  how to add SSO to a published web application in Azure using OpenID Connect. You can follow the steps exactly and build their demo version to test it out, or follow their steps at the bottom that show how to implement SSO in your own application.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect

For more details refer this documents:

**1)** https://midnightprogrammer.net/post/single-sign-on-in-aspnet-core-with-azure-active-directory/

**2)** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp

Comment: Thank you. I have seen these but they are very different from my scenario.

Comment: any solution to this...i am also looking for same problem